# Regex pattern in javascript to change a value between characters of input's name attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, json

I need your help to create a regex pattern to extract a character from the value of the attribute "name" of an html input.

This is because, with a button I clone dynamically a "select" and some input text, so I need to keep the same syntax of their attribute "name" value.

Example:

```
<input id="search-words02" type="text" name="words[1][element]">
<select id="search-words03" title="Auteur" name="words[1][target]">
  <option value="ALL">hello</option>
</select>
```

So I have **words[1][element]** and **words[1][target]**

And to submit the form in a json format with all fields dynamically cloned, I need to increment the words[**1**][element] and have  words[**2**][element] or words[**3**][element].

So my json could be :

```
{
        "words":        {
            "0":
            {
                "element":"",
                "target":""
            },
            "1":
            {
                "element":"2",
                "target":"GES"
            }
            "2":
            {
                "element":"3",
                "target":"XXX"
            }
}
```

So I guess my pattern should take and replace the character in the first tab, but I have no idea how the regex should be to do that..

Anyone can help me to build this regex and tell me how I can replace the found term ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's only one number in your name attribute, you can easily extract it with "\d" like below

```
var w = "words[1][element]";
var num = parseInt(/\d+/.exec(w)) + 1;
w = w.replace(/\d+/, num);
```

Comment: Thanks ! This solution works, i will adjust the regex if the name change, but for now this as you said, only one number.